# Green Card Holder Married to USA Citizen

Tags: immigration, taxes, marriage

I am a green card holder and I just got married to a US citizen. We got married out of the US. Do we have to submit any particular documentation since we are planning to file taxes together? My company filed for my green card a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

The only document you need to submit to indicate that you're filing a joint tax return is the tax return itself.  If you were married in 2019, the first tax return for which you'll do this is your 2019 tax return, due in April 2020.  If you were married earlier this month then you'll have to wait a year; your filing status for your 2019 returns will remain *single* or whatever it was before you were married.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply we where married back in 2019 December so should i wait for next year or file the tax return together

Comment: @ZCoder because you were married during 2019, your marital status for 2019 is *married.*  Whether to file one return ("married filing jointly") or two ("married filing separately") is a decision for you to make with your tax advisor, if any.

Answer (score 2):

If either the permanent resident or the citizen is changing his/her name as a result of the marriage, that partner will need to [obtain a new social security card](https://faq.ssa.gov/en-US/Topic/article/KA-01981), as well as all the other steps in changing one's name. If either or both partners are employed, the employee may wish to file a [new form W-4](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-4) with their employer so taxes withheld will be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks you! we are not changing names that's a good news :)

Comment: On the necessity of obtaining a new social security card after marriage: my mother got hers about 45 years after her marriage to my father.

Comment: @phoog One will probably want a new driver license after a name change. For RealID the state cross-checks the name with social security, or so I understand.

Comment: @GerardAshton perhaps so.  This was long before Real ID came about.  I don't know whether my mother now has a Real ID license.  I do not -- I prefer not having to renew in person.